# Convert List to a HasMap of String & ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I use java 1.6.
I have an iterator on ArrayList. For each Java Bean, it return me values in below format.

```
id="my_Bean" name="my Bean" value="Red"
```

For each iteration it is possible that I will get the same id & name with different "value".

I want to convert it into a HashMap (maybe), which should give me values in below format.

```
collection= { {id= "my_Bean", name= "my Bean", values= ["Red", "Blue", "Green"]}, .....& so on.. }
```

I'm unable to write the logic for it. Any help will be great.

Comment: do you mean you have composite keys with id and name and list of values?

Comment: @almasshaikh maybe Yes, am not sure about it

Comment: For a given id, will the name always be the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use composite key in HashMap<> to add your bean object. I have added `values` in your bean which  is List of the `value` for same bean whose id and name is same.

Below is the code :

```
        HashMap<String, My_Bean> hashMap = new HashMap<String, My_Bean>();
        for(int i=0;i<elist.size();i++)
        {
            My_Bean obj = elist.get(i);

            String key = obj.getId()+"-"+obj.getName();

            if(hashMap.containsKey(key)){
                List<String> values = hashMap.get(key).getValues();
                if(values != null) {
                    hashMap.get(key).getValues().add(obj.getValue());
                }else{
                    hashMap.get(key).setValues(new ArrayList<String>());
                    hashMap.get(key).getValues().add(obj.getValue());
                }
            }
            else{
                hashMap.put(key, obj);
                hashMap.get(key).setValues(new ArrayList<String>());
                hashMap.get(key).getValues().add(obj.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Here `elist` is the list of your bean object. I have iterate your bean list and add bean object to HashMap if not present with the key ( combination of `id-name` ) with adding new values list with present bean's `value` value, if bean is already there than take values list and add value to that list.

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: upvote for using containsKey, which i forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

You can make keys for your map in this way

```
String key = id + "-" + name;
```

Comment: If you want to have a map of String and Array fro example Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your bean has getters the following approach may be of use. A composite key is used and the value of the `Map` is a `List<Bean>` (it could obviously be e.g. a `List<String>`s instead if that is desired).

So, I would use a loop and to collect all values and then use a composite key. One way to go is to use the `Pair` class from `commons-lang3`:

```
final Map<Pair<String, String>, List<Bean>> map = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, List<Bean>>();
for (final Iterator<Bean> itr = beans.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    Bean bean = itr.next();
    final Pair<String, String> key = Pair.of(bean.getId(), bean.getName());
    List<Bean> value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        value = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    value.add(bean);
}
```

In your Maven POM or similar, import the following artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This approach is safe if you don't know what your ids and names will look like. If your key e.g. contains the letter `-` a composite key should not be `id + "-" + name´.

Also note that there are many libraries out there that offer `Pair`-classes or similar. Sometimes the class may be called a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is one solution:

I assume you have getters/setters on your object fields.

Make the value field of your bean also an ArrayList, and at the iteration step you can do like:

```
// Create collection which will store the duplicates (which have same name and id)

Map collection = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

for(referenceElement:yourArrayList){
  for(nextElement:yourArrayList){
     if(referenceElement.getId==nextElement.getId
        &&referenceElement.getName.equals(nextElement.getName)){
          MyBean duplicate = new MyBean();
          ArrayList values = new ArrayList<String>();
          values.add(referenceElement.getValue);
          values.add(nextElement.getValue);
          collection.put("id= "+duplicate.setId(referenceElement.getId)+", "
          +"name= "+duplicate.setName(referenceElement.getName), duplicate.setValue(values);
                                                            }
                                 }
}
```

Also a tip to compare bean objects of your list is to implement `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (InputBean inputBean : inputBeanList)
    {
        String key = inputBean.getId() + "," + inputBean.getName();
        if (resultMap.containsKey(key))
        {
            resultMap.get(key).add(inputBean.getValue());
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            resultList.add(inputBean.getValue());
            resultMap.put(key, resultList);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("resultMap : " + resultMap);
```